# How is $x^2+1=(1/{x^2})[1-{1}/{x^2}+{1}/{x^4}-{1}/{x^6}+\cdots]$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The author of my book writes:

$$x^2+1=x^2\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$

$$=\frac{1}{x^2}\left[1-\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^4}-\frac{1}{x^6}+\cdots\right]$$

I do not understand the last step. How did the author write the last step. Please help.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AlexR thanks for letting me know

Comment: Are you sure that this equation holds?

Comment: Take $x = 1/2$. $\text{LHS} = 5/4$ and $\text{RHS} \rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think they are equal. As others have said
$$
\frac{x^2}{1+x^2} = 1 - \frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{x^4} \dots \text{ for } \left\lvert \frac{-1}{x^2} \right\rvert < 1
$$

so for $x = \sqrt{2}$
$$
\frac{1}{x^2} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{x^4} \dots \right) = \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{2}{3} \right) = \frac{1}{3}.
$$

However $x^2+1 = 3 \neq \frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: (+1) Thank you so much for taking me out of the indescribable frustration I have been for the past hour.

Answer (score 5):

I believe your author intended to write
$$
\frac{1}{x^2+1}=\frac{1}{x^2\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}
\\
=\frac{1}{x^2}\left[1-\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^4}-\frac{1}{x^6}+\cdots\right]
$$

Comment: (+1) Hmmmm yes must be (I don't know for sure) :) Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Formula is not correct. Take the sum of a [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula):

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} ar^i=\frac{a}{1-r}$$

Lets work backward from your last equation:

$$\frac{1}{x^2}\left[1-\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^4}-\frac{1}{x^6}+\cdots\right]=\frac{1}{x^2}\left[\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{x^{4}}\right)^i-x^2\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{x^{4}}\right)^i+x^2\right]=$$

The two sums in the brackets are simply geometric sums with $r=\frac{1}{x^4}$, thus:

$$\left[\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{x^{4}}\right)^i-x^2\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{x^{4}}\right)^i+x^2\right]=\left[\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{x^4}}-\frac{x^2}{1-\frac{1}{x^4}} +x^2\right]=\left[\frac{1-x^2+(1-\frac{1}{x^4})x^2}{1-\frac{1}{x^4}}\right]$$

The last equation simplifies to:

$$\left[\frac{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}{1-\frac{1}{x^4}}\right]=\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\implies x^2+1=\frac{1}{x^2+1}???$$ This is not correct

Answer (score 1):

You may write $$x^2 + 1 = x^2(1 + \frac{1}{x^2})$$

as $$\frac{1}{(1 + \frac{1}{x^2})} = \frac{x^2}{1 + x^2}$$

and 
$$\frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{x^2}}  = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{x^{2n}}$$

> **Edit:** To avoid any more downvotes, the author has made a mistake, clearly the equation does not hold, this was just an attemptive to reinterpret whatever the author's intention was.

Comment: I still don't get it :/ My bracket is $(1+\frac{1}{x^2})$ and not $\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}$

Comment: I saw the edit . Your formula works ,except that it's confusing that my fraction is the inverse of yours. Mine is $\frac{1+x^2}{x^2}$ while yours is $\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$

Comment: (+1) for the continued support. I'm sorry I don't get it, let me try to explain what's worrying me, So $\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{x^{2n}} \implies \frac{1+x^2}{x^2} = \frac{1}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{x^{2n}}}$ which means $1+x^2=\frac{x^2}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{x^{2n}}} \neq \frac{1}{x^2} [1-1/x^2+1/x^4+\cdots]$

Comment: Your equation is wrong then. No need to downvote.

Comment: That is what I'm surprised about too, apparently the author and you and others are displaying workings that don't make sense.

Comment: What we wrote holds. It must have been a typing or something from the author.